# Unity 2D - Destructible Terrain or Ignore Poly Collider over Spritemask

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

I'm trying to make a worms-like terrain, but I'm a little confused on how to accomplish that.

I'm trying to add a new Spritemask based on my collision point, but I need to re-draw or ignore my Polygon Collider 2D Under the spritemask.

[image]

Is there any way to ignore my collider over the mask and make my player go "into" the hole ? Or I'm going the wrong way and there have a better way to accomplish that ?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to remove the collider and add it again, it will automatically fit into new sprite shape.

```
Delete(GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>())
AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>()
```

It works but is quite slow, so it is ok for worms-like game.